# Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

Error when I execute `terraform destroy`  in some separate folder that containt kubernetes/helm provider I face an error:
`Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials`.
After execution of terraform apply/refresh terraform destroy works fine.
This happends after Terraform update (`0.13.7`=>`0.14.11`). In Terraform v0.13.7 `terraform destroy` works fine.
EKS version: `1.25`, kubectl: `1.25.15`, Terraform: `0.14.11`.

versions.tf configuration:

```
terraform {
  required_version = "0.14.11"
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "4.60.0"
    }
    helm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/helm"
      version = "2.9.0"
    }
    null = {
      source  = "hashicorp/null"
      version = "3.2.1"
    }
  }
  backend "s3" { ...}
}

provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.eks.endpoint
    token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.eks.token
    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.eks.certificate_authority.0.data)
  }
}
```

[This fix](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/issues/1234) didn't help (export KUBE_CONFIG_PATH=<path_to config>). Also, this fix isn't a suitable solution, since Teraform will also be executed from AWS CodePipeline.
How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried different solutions:

- updating kubernetes/helm providers;
- setting environment variable KUBE_CONFIG_PATH;
- changing the connection type in kubernetes/helm provider.

But everything was without success.
The only solution that really fixed the problem was update to the Terraform version `0.15.5`.
I hope, it will help somebody.